# How can I see if the file "readthedocs.yml" is used at all?

Tags: read-the-docs

How can I check in the build logs if readthedocs.yml has been used?

This should install sphinx-argparse but it does not.

My project: https://gpxity.readthedocs.io

I added readthedocs.yml with

> ```
>  extra_requirements: 
>
>    - doc
> ```

and in setup.py:

> extras_require={ ...'doc': ['sphinx', 'sphinx-autodoc-annotation', 'sphinx-argparse']}

Answer (score 0):

In readthedocs.yml, I had to replace setup_py_install with pip_install.

Since this is an inconstistent configuration according to the documentation, it would be nice to get a warning or even an error message.

See [docs.readthedocs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml-config.html?highlight=setup_py_install#python-extra-requirements)